# A continuous injective group homomorphism $GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \to O(n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, continuity, group-homomorphism, continuous-homomorphisms

Is there a continuous injective group homomorphism $GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \to O(n)$?

I'm struggling to construct one - given a matrix $A$ in $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, how can we construct a matrix $O(n)$ in terms of $A$? I've tried constructions like $AA^T$, $A^{-1}A^T$, $A+A^T$, $A^{-1}+A^T$, and none work (not even mapping to $O(n)$, let alone being injective).

Comment: $GL_n$ would have to have a suitable normal subgroup to serve as the kernel of the homomorphism, but there is no such normal subgroup. So no, no such homomorphism (injective or otherwise) exists

Comment: @BenGrossmann Can you explain what you mean by "suitable normal subgroup"? Also, continuous *non*-injective group homomorphisms $GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \to O(n)$ do exist.

Comment: There’s the map that takes $A$ to $I$ when $A$ has a positive determinant and $-I$ when $A$ has a negative determinant and there’s the trivial homomorphism, but I’m not aware of any others

Comment: I was thinking of the special orthogonal group when I made that comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not *any* continuous injection $GL_n(\mathbb{R})\to O(n)$ (for $n>0$).  This follows from the [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) theorem, which implies in particular that a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has no continuous injection to $\mathbb{R}^m$ for $m<n$.  Since $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a manifold of dimension $n^2$ and $O(n)$ is a manifold of dimension $n(n-1)/2$, a continuous injection $GL_n(\mathbb{R})\to O(n)$ would locally give a continuous injection from an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n(n-1)/2}$, which is impossible.